# Can an X server run without a physical screen?

Tags: linux, xserver

We need to run an application using the graphic card driver.

However the machine does not have a screen. Is it possible to have this running ?

Xfvb seems not be an option since it uses software rendering instead of the graphic card driver.

Thanks for your suggestions/answers.

Comment: You need to be more specific what you want to do with the "graphics card driver".

Comment: A graphic card driver will not function without a graphic card. It is however rare for an X app to be aware of drivers. Do you really need it?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [VNC module for X](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=vnc4server). You can load it by editing your xorg.conf:

```
Section "Module"
    Load "vnc"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Option "SecurityTypes" "None"
EndSection
```

It will connect X to the network instead of to a physical screen, and it supposedly supports hardware acceleration with some drivers.

See http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-279069.html